# Fragment não aparece em um Toolbar com TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou tentando mostrar 2 layouts de lista na mesma activity usando o ViewPager, mas por alguma razão os layouts não estão sendo mostrados na tela da aplicação (estão em branco), porém, ao debugar, as linhas do oncreateview estão sendo lidas, ou seja, o fragment está sendo chamado.

layoutdaactivity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityTabs.java

```
public class ListSubcategoriaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager pager;
private SubcategoriaPagerAdapter adapter;
private TabLayout tabs;
private CharSequence titles[] = {"Receita", "Despesa"};
int numboftabs = 2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_subcat);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    adapter = new SubcategoriaPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles,  numboftabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor));
    tabs.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor), getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor));
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    changeTabsFont();
}



private void changeTabsFont() {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabs.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
public class SubcategoriaPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
CharSequence[] titles;
int numOfTabs;

public SubcategoriaPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.titles = mTitles;
    this.numOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        SubcategoriaReceita tb1 = new SubcategoriaReceita();
        return tb1;
    } else {
        SubcategoriaDespesa tb2 = new SubcategoriaDespesa();
        return tb2;
    }
}


}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class SubcategoriaReceita extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public SubcategoriaReceita() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment SubcategoriaReceita.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SubcategoriaReceita newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SubcategoriaReceita fragment = new SubcategoriaReceita();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subcategoria_receita, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recySub);
    refreshLista();

    return v ;
}

private void refreshLista(){
    CategoriaDAO cDAO = new CategoriaDAO(getContext());
    SubCategoriaDAO sDAO = new SubCategoriaDAO(getContext());
    List<Categoria> cList = cDAO.getLista(0);
    for (Categoria c : cList){
        List<SubCategoria> sList = sDAO.getLista(c.getId());
        c.setChildList(sList);
    }
    SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter adapter = new SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter(getContext(), cList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Fragment1.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recySub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Adapter do RecyclerView (Os métodos onBind dele não estão parando no breakpoint quando eu debugo)

```
public class SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<CategoriaViewHolder,SubcategoriaViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;


public SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter(Context context, @NonNull List<? extends ParentListItem> categoriaList){
    super(categoriaList);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public SubcategoriaViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategoria_row, childViewGroup, false);
    return new SubcategoriaViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public CategoriaViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup parentViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row, parentViewGroup, false);
    return new CategoriaViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindParentViewHolder(CategoriaViewHolder parentViewHolder, int position, ParentListItem parentListItem) {
    Categoria categoria = (Categoria) parentListItem;
    parentViewHolder.bind(categoria);
 }

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(SubcategoriaViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, Object childListItem) {
    SubCategoria subCategoria = (SubCategoria) childListItem;
    childViewHolder.bind(subCategoria);
}


}
```

Tela do problema

[image]

Obrigado desde já pessoal.

Comment: Não parece haver erros para mim, você já botou um Log para ver se sua lista não está vindo vazia do DAO?

Comment: Já sim, o problema em si não é a lista, pois ela vem populada, o fragment está funcionando, só o recycler não está sendo populado (Vou postar o adapter) @Luiz